# Create temp tables in Amazon RDS PostgreSQL read-replica

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, read-only-database

I have dozens of legacy stored procedures which create temporary tables inside for collecting results for a read-only application.

I've created a read-replica of my PostgreSQL in Amazon RDS and tried to perform this procedures, but failed, as it doesn't allow to create even temporary tables in a read-only transaction.

Are any ways how to solve this issue with minimal efforts?

Comment: Move those queries to the master.  PostgreSQL currently does not allow creating temporary tables on read-only replicas, this is not an RDS specific issue.

Comment: @dezso Great advice, read please my question more carefully: these procedures are used for reading data and I can not change DB type, only read-replica

Comment: Eh, you are right, as the way of maintaining a replica is different in RDS than in plain PostgreSQL, it is an RDS specific issue, with its effect being very similar in both cases :D  Unfortunately for you, read replicas are also read-only, so no temp tables there.

Answer (score 3):

As the most easy way which I found to solve this issue - is wrapping all "temporary tables" into separate stored procedures, which return `TABLE(...)` type, and then use Common Table Expressions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html).

Comment: How much work it will be to rewrite those functions?

Comment: 2-4 hours. I've already did it :) Look, I have no choice.

Comment: So you didn't have hundreds of them, that's good news :D